# No tag was defined for name: ajax

Tags: ajax, eclipse, jsf

I am using Eclipse / jsf  to create my web application.
I was trying to solve a problem like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645593/change-inputtext-value-from-listener-method#)

I included:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<jsp:root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

My code:

```
<h:inputText id="cod" value="#{myBean.nwcode}"
size="25" maxlength="30" required="true" requiredMessage="CODE est obligatoire" >
<f:ajax listener="#{myBean.namedChanged}"  render="@form"/>
                                </h:inputText>
```

What is missing?.

If  Tag is impossible to be used in this case, please show me how to use valueChangeListener property because I already implemented a method:

```
    public void OnproCodeChangeCheckValid(ValueChangeEvent VChEvnt)
{
    if(!((String)VChEvnt.getNewValue()).equals(null)&&!((String)VChEvnt.getNewValue()).trim().isEmpty())
    {
    nwprofvalid=!estprofileexist((String)VChEvnt.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

But this method hasn't been invoked by simply saying:

```
valueChangeListener="#{myBean.OnproCodeChangeCheckValid}"
```

Maybe because it needs a param, so how to passe it?.
Any ideas?.

Many thanks in advance.

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /ajoutProfile.jspx @57,21 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)

com.sun.facelets.tag.TagException: /ajoutProfile.jspx @57,21 <f:ajax> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:193)
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:194)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:232)
    com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:105)
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
    com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)

    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:271)
```

Comment: try this `valueChangeListener="#{myBean.OnproCodeChangeCheckValid}"`

Comment: @Scorpion, Sorry, but I did that, typing error in my question.

Comment: try this namespaces `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">`

Comment: @Scorpion, still no <f:ajax> the same problem, thanks.

Comment: post your stack trace please.

Comment: Which JSF version are you using ?

Comment: @TiyebBellal that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297098/jsf2-0-tags-not-found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<f:ajax>` was introduced in JSF 2.0. Your problem symptoms suggest that you're using JSF 1.x which lacks the `<f:ajax>` tag. At least, the presence of `com.sun.facelets.*` classes in the stack trace confirms that you're using Facelets 1.x which in turn confirms that you're using JSF 1.x. Namely, in JSF 2.x, the Facelets classes were moved to `com.sun.faces.facelets.*` with here and there some class refactoring (e.g. the `FaceletViewHandler` doesn't exist anymore).

The stack trace also confirms that you've Ajax4JSF installed. In that case, just use `<a4j:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>` to solve the problem based on the answer you found.